# How to check if make uninstall will work

Tags: linux, macos, unix, uninstall, make

FYI I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan.

I compile things using CMake and `make` on my machine on a day to day basis, but without so far having understood CMake or `make` in any respectable depth at all (I have found it difficult to find good tutorials on them in the past).

The command `sudo make install` always makes me nervous because I'm not sure if I can *uninstall* it later if I choose to.

I know that `make -n install` will do a "fake install" whereby it tells me what it would do without actually doing it, thus allowing me to figure out what the install did and how to reverse it manually; but that's a pain ...

I understand that if I'm lucky, the developers of the software would have made *uninstall* instructions and `make uninstall` would work.

My question is, (given that I don't know anything about `make`,) how do I quickly check if `make uninstall` will work, before I do `sudo make install`?

Is it as simple as text-searching the term "uninstall" in the `Makefile` or something like that?

Comment: Yes it is... :-)
In the Makefile there are different sections. (You can enumerate them in the shell by pressing tab after you write make and before you press enter). 
Search the one with `uninstall` and check if it is all as you think.  More easy to say than to do even because the makefile of a big program can be rather complex. Use an editor that has syntax highlighting. It will help a lot. Good luck.

Comment: Oh good. So much for the long question! Thank you. Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: _"Yes it is..."_ should be the shorter answer of SuperUser history `:-)`. I added some words more...

Comment: `make -n uninstall` will show an error if there is no `uninstall` target.

Comment: Ah yes. That would be the quickest way to check if there is `uninstall`. I should have thought of that given what I already knew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes it is...

In the Makefile there are different sections.
You can enumerate them  by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> after you write `make` (but before you press <kbd>enter</kbd> `;-)`).
Search the one with `uninstall` and check if it is all as you think.

By the way it is often more easy to say than to do, even because the `Makefile` of a big program can be rather complex. On the other side if it is complex maybe they take good care of the `unistall` section too.

**Suggestion:** use an editor that has syntax highlighting. It will help a lot.

You can do your Makefile for your own purposes, i.e. to create a pdf file from the Latex source too.

```
# Makefile .
default:
        @echo
        @echo "Possible builds are:"
        @echo " all"
        @echo " pdf"
        @echo " ps"
        @echo " clean"
        @echo

all:
        latex lett.01.tex
        dvips lett.01.dvi
        dvipdf lett.01.dvi

pdf: 
        latex lett.01.tex
        dvipdf lett.01.dvi

ps: 
        latex lett.01.tex
        dvips lett.01.dvi

clean:
        rm -f lett.01.pdf lett.01.ps
        rm -f *.log *.dvi *.aux *.end
```

**References**

- The [gnu make guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). (I know you are not with gnu, just for reference).
- The [first example](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/) simple enough about a *make tutorial* popped out from internet.
- An example [more complex](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2015/08/01/simple-c-plus-plus-from-makefiles-to-xcode-builds/), with variables and so on..

Comment: You can check for `Makefile` examples on your own system too with `wc -l $(locate Makefile | grep -v "\.")` and see the one of the length that you feel ready to _face_ today...  In the OP specific case you can restrict the search with  a `grep ninstall `...